# Live Mode Stripe Error `can't communicate with our payment processor because the API key is invalid.`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I got my app working perfectly on Stripe's test mode, but when I flipped the toggle switch to `live` on the Stripe dashboard and changed my `stripe_publishable_key` and `stripe_secret_key` on my `secrets.yml` file I keep getting the error:

> Stripe Checkout can't communicate with our payment processor because
>   the API key is invalid. Please contact the website owner or
>   support@stripe.com.

I'm not even sure what code to put on here to help people troubleshoot because everything was working fine in test mode, but here's the structure of my `secrets.yml`:

```
development:
  secret_key_base: ***SECRET KEY BASE HERE***
  stripe_publishable_key: ***PUBLISHABLE KEY HERE***
  stripe_secret_key:  ***SECRET KEY HERE***

test:
  secret_key_base: ***SECRET KEY BASE HERE***

# Do not keep production secrets in the repository,
# instead read values from the environment.
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
  stripe_publishable_key: ENV['stripe_publishable_key']
  stripe_secret_key: ENV['stripe_publishable_key']
```

I checked with other posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19216508/stripe-invalid-api-key-provided) but none of these steps fixed the issue.  Can anyone add any insight?

With the edits found in the comments section, the error has disappeared, but these console errors (along with an eternal pinwheel) persist:

[image]

Comment: not exactly sure how you have this set up, is it on heroku or something?  Do you need to add "<%=   %>" around the ENV variables in production?

Comment: @RockwellRice, This is on Heroku.  And that's definitely a step forward with the `<%= %>`.  Now I don't get the error message, but it pinwheels indefinitely and I get `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)` in my console...

Comment: so you changed the variables in the settings section of the heroku dashboard for that app, correct?

Comment: @RockwellRice, yes, with `heroku config:set PUBLISHABLE_KEY=...` etc.

Comment: well just to be clear if you wrote "PUBLISHABLE_KEY" but your file above says "stripe_publishable_key" they are not the same, the names need to be exact, do the variables have the exact same name?

Comment: @RockwellRice, thanks again for the good catch.  However, saving the correct variable names in Heroku did not, unfortunately, change my console errors.  I'm putting a picture in the OP.

Comment: Is there an error in the stripe logs that you could post or check? Also it may help to have the js file, not sure what "message" is supposed to be or how t is defined but it looks like it is not getting whatever variable that is suppose to be.

Comment: @RockwellRice, the stripe logs show `200 OK` for both of my attempts, showing my correct information in the object, but I checked in the `subscriptions` tab and neither subscription was recorded.

Answer (score 1):

Recheck your *public key* and make sure by mistake you didn't put semicolon `;` at the end of the key.

Answer (score 0):

just spent a while debugging only to realize I set the key this way:

```
export PUBLISHABLE_KEY="pk_test_1234567"
```

which does *not* work

```
export PUBLISHABLE_KEY=pk_test_1234567
```

works as expected (dont wrap in quotes)
for whatever reason, I did not notice I did this this right away..

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the keys since *this is wrong*:

> `stripe_secret_key: ENV['stripe_publishable_key']`

The secret key in for use in your javascript, **reverse the keys** and put the **publishable key** in the **public javascript**.

```
// sk_(test|live) = "Secret key"
stripe_publishable_key: 'sk_live_1234567890asdfg';

// pk_(test|live) = "Publishable key"
stripe_secret_key:      'pk_live_1234567890asdfg';
```

Your javascript (public facing, public visible) key has `pk` in it (public key).

If you use the `sk` in the javascript (reversing them), it won't work.